# Embedded Fonts in AS3 and IE: Is the syntax correct?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, embedded-fonts

I spent a good bit of time this morning trying multiple solutions I found throughout the site but unfortunately, none of them truly worked.  Here's the problem.  I believe that my process of font embedding is working because I purposely removed the fonts from my machine and I see them showing up in the flash player.  However, they do not show up on our Windows test machine (in either IE or FF) and I can't seem to figure out why.  As I mentioned, I tried several of the solutions found throughout the site but it didn't seem to make a difference.  Here is excepts of the class and constructor that I have built:

```
public class MyClass {
    [Embed(source = "../../fonts/DroidSans.ttf", 
        fontName = "DroidSans", 
        mimeType = "application/x-font-truetype", 
        fontWeight = "normal", 
        fontStyle = "normal", 
        unicodeRange =  "U+0041-U+005A, U+0061-U+007A, U+0030-U+0039, U+002E-U+002E",
        embedAsCFF = "false")]
    private var droidSansFont:Class;

    [Embed(source = "../../fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf", 
        fontName = "DroidSansBold", 
        mimeType = "application/x-font-truetype", 
        fontWeight = "normal", 
        fontStyle = "normal", 
        unicodeRange =  "U+0041-U+005A, U+0061-U+007A, U+0030-U+0039, U+002E-U+002E",
        embedAsCFF = "false")]
    private var droidSansBoldFont:Class;
    .
    .
    .
    public function MyClass() {
        _flVersion = String(flash.system.Capabilities.version);
        _baseFont = (_flVersion.indexOf("10,") != -1) ? "Arial" : "DroidSans";
        _boldFont = (_flVersion.indexOf("10,") != -1) ? "Arial" : "DroidSansBold";

        buttonFormat = new TextFormat();
        buttonFormat.font = _baseFont;
        buttonFormat.size = 10;
        buttonFormat.color = 0x000000;
        buttonFormat.bold = false;
        buttonFormat.align = "center";
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

If anyone can offer up a solution or point me in the right direction, it would be most helpful.

Comment: So just a quick update; it appears that font embedding is not working in any of the browsers I am testing (i.e. the code is completely failing).

Comment: Are you setting embedFonts=true on your TextField?  And what's with the version 10 test?  You're only using embedded fonts for flash player 10? (but be careful with this test - it could match in version 12,10,115)

Comment: Darn, I'm not setting embedFont=true.  I incorrectly assumed that wasn't required.  Let me try that.

Comment: Hopefully that should do it.  I'll post an answer, in case it works, so you can accept it.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting embedFonts=true on your TextField?

And be careful with version test:

```
_flVersion.indexOf("10,")!=-1
```

This could match anywhere in the version String.  You negaitve logic is confusing me a little, but thinking carefully, you check will DISABLE embeded fonts in Flash Player versions, for example: 10,1,100 and 12,10,115

Assuming you do intend to disable embedded fonts in FP10, you could possibly change your condition to the following (which won't match 12,10,115):

```
_flVersion.indexOf("10,")==0
```

I'd then put this in a commented getter function to make your code more readable:

```
// No embedded fonts for flash player 10
private static var _flVersion:String = String(flash.system.Capabilities.version);
private function get use_embedded_fonts():Boolean {
  return _flVersion.indexOf("10,")!=0;
}
```

Also, you'll only want to set the embed flag when using the embedded Droid font and not Arial:

```
_baseFont = (!use_embedded_fonts) ? "Arial" : "DroidSans";
_boldFont = (!use_embedded_fonts) ? "Arial" : "DroidSansBold";
_embed_flag = use_embedded_fonts;

textfield.embedFonts = _embed_flag;
...
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions.  @Jeff - I made the changes you suggested as well as adding embedFonts = true.  Once I added that, the text disappeared which according to the api docs means that fonts I thought I was embedding are either not actually embedding (which when I compile the SWF I see the size difference) or I'm not specifying the correct name.  Would that be your assessment as well?  Also, the above class is creating all of the TextFormat objects to be dolled out via a method to other classes.  I tried this all in one class just in case but that produced the same results.

Comment: UPDATE: So I've noticed that if I replace buttonFormat.font = _baseFont; with buttonFormat.font = "DroidSans" it works.  I'm wondering if the problem is initialization.  Testing now...